# InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file in get response JS API LARAVEL Storage FTP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ftp, httpresponse

example image error : [image]

is there something wrong with my controller?

why ftp storage not working?

example config filesystemd :

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'ftp')

'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
            'root'     => '/web',
        ],
```

config file .env :

```
FTP_HOST=exampleftpserver.com
FTP_USERNAME=userftp
FTP_PASSWORD=password123
```

example controller :

```
$explode = explode('#',$lampiran->lampiran_gambar);
                    foreach($explode as $row){
                        if($row == null){
                          $row1[] = 'null';
                        }else{
                        $row1[] = Storage::disk('ftp')->get('/lampiranSurat/' . $row);
                        }
                    }
                if($pegawai_pejabat->jenis_jabatan_id == 1){
                    return response()->json([
                        'meta' => [
                            'code' => 200,
                            'status' => 'success',
                            'message' => 'Data Ditemukan',
                        ],
                        'data_verifikasi' => $verifikasi,
                        'lampiran_gambar' => $row1,
                        'pegawai_verif'   => $pegawai_verif,
                    ]);
                }
```

Comment: Sounds like you had something in `$row` that does not contain valid UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I've used :  mb_convert_encoding($row1, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTFIhl6PsZucLYpzRWLGxwdC0BiHSVu5/view

Comment: Having the from and to encoding the same with that function call, I don't think that makes any sense. And it looks like this has little to do with FTP then, but is about the attempt to JSON-encode the binary file data ...?